# How to create RSS feed for certain Stack Exchange site

Tags: support, feed

How can I create RSS feed for Buddhism Stack Exchange site? What about Academia site?

Cannot find the RSS button anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, the feed link is located in the bottom of the page. For Buddhism.SE it would be https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/feeds and for Academia.SE it would be https://academia.stackexchange.com/feeds.